# Powershell Wait-Process

Tags: powershell, wait

I have used Wait-Process in the past and it works fine. This time I am trying to close down visual studio gracefully (allow time to save any unsaved files) and once that is completed for notepad to open.

**(Get-Process devenv).CloseMainWindow() | Wait-Process | notepad**

Unfortunately while Visual Studio does close gracefully, notepad pops up simultaneously with the save files dialog. Why in this instance does Wait-Process not work as per norm. There is a powershell error accompanied which I cannot understand at the moment.

***Wait-Process : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input. At line:1 char:54 (Get-Process devenv).CloseMainWindow() | Wait-Process <<<<***

However I have done many DoSomethingA | WaitProcess | DoSomethingB commands which work. I can't figure out the different scenario here.

Comment: (Get-Process devenv).CloseMainWindow() isn't piping a process..

Comment: Ah ok, so there is nothing to wait for is what you are saying. Is there anyway I can achieve what I am trying to?

Comment: I've posted an answer. Try it... and give me a feedback

Comment: "(Get-Process devenv).CloseMainWindow() isn't piping a process" - I thought you were saying that CloseMainWindow() does not return a process so there is nothing to pipe into Wait-Process. So effectively I can't achieve what I'm trying to via CloseMainWindow() and I was asking if there was a better way to achieve the effect I was looking for or have I misunderstood completely?

Comment: If code in my answer doesn't do what you expect.. then I don't understood your need. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 2):

CloseMainWindow returns a Boolean value which is piped to Wait-Process, but Wait-Process expects a process object and not a Boolean value. Give this a try

```
Get-Process devenv | ForEach-Object {
    $null=$_.CloseMainWindow()
    Wait-Process -Id $_.id
    notepad
}
```

Comment: That makes sense, is there any way I can achieve what I am trying to?

Comment: Maybe capture the result and respond based on the value you get back.

Comment: But that's the problem, how do I get the next process to wait for the CloseMainWindow() to return it's value. It'll return a bool but the next process will have kicked off.

Comment: If there's more than one devenv process: Get-Process devenv |Foreach {$_.CloseMainWindow()}

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
Get-Process devenv | % {$_.CloseMainWindow()}; wait-process devenv -ea silentlycontinue ; notepad
```

Comment: Sorry for some reason I didn't see this Christian and I was confused why you were saying you'd posted a solution! This does work as expected, thanks for the reply.